# Django - filtering model objects

Tags: python, django

I have some model:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_stop = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

I try to filter all Reservations:

```
@login_required
def reservations_list_view(request):
    reservations = Reservation.objects.all() 
    return render(request, 'reservations/reservations_list.html', {'reservations': reservations})
```

At this moment - i skipped this filter:
reservations = Reservation.objects.filter( ... ) - I dont know what should I use.

I tried e.g.

```
reservations = Reservation.objects.filter(name__exact='Tom')
```

buy still not working.

I'd like to see all Reservations e.g. after today (start_date) and here is my problem. Could u help with it?

Comment: Does "after" today, means you include/exclude reservations that start today? What about reservations that are still running (so stap on/after today)?

Comment: It's only some example. So 'after' means e.g. include.

Comment: What error you are getting @TomaszBonarkiewicz ?

Comment: @TomaszBonarkiewicz: are we talking about starting, or ending?

Comment: @Sanu K yadav - no errors

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem - its only example, so e.g. starting

Comment: reservations = Reservation.objects.filter(name__contains= 'Tom'), Try like command.

Comment: @Sanu K yadav - yes, i tried, still the same - have all Reservation objects.

Comment: go to the django shell and query the table >> python mange.py shell >> from appname.models import models

Comment: @TomaszBonarkiewicz: the filtering of `name__exact='Tom'` does not seem to match your "real" problem of filtering after today?

Comment: Yea, I used shell, and there working ok.
Problem was in my filters.py, some stupid mistake. 
Thank u for help!

Answer (score -1):

We can obtain the current date with `now().date()` from [**`django.utils.timezone`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now). Then we can filter the `Reservation`s that have a `date_start` that is greater than, or equal to that date with the [**`__gte`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte):

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

@login_required
def reservations_list_view(request):
    reservations = Reservation.objects.filter(date_start__gte=now().date()) 
    return render(
        request,
        'reservations/reservations_list.html',
        {'reservations': reservations}
    )
```

Comment: Nope, still have all Reservation objects in my list.

Comment: @TomaszBonarkiewicz: since you set the default to `now()`, that's not per se suprisingly :)

Comment: @TomaszBonarkiewicz: Can you inspect the database and look if there are records that start before today? Can you edit your question and include the (sample) data in the database?